# polyglossia and vertical tabular alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, polyglossia

I have two `tabular` side by side and I want their tops aligned.

When I use English language, it works fine.

When I use Arabic language, the tables suddenly become bottom-aligned, even though I used the `[t]` specification.  For the Arabic I have used Times New Roman font, but this isn't essential.  I am using the booktabs package.

I am guessing the problem lies in `Bidi` or `polyglossia`, but I don't know.

The MWE places both on the screen to show the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}[t]{rl} \toprule
كلمة&كلمة\\ \midrule
كلمة&كلمة\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl} \toprule
كلمة&كلمة\\ \midrule
كلمة&كلمة\\
كلمة&كلمة\\
كلمة&كلمة\\
كلمة&كلمة\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{english}
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl} \toprule
word&word\\ \midrule
word&word\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl} \toprule
word&word\\ \midrule
word&word\\
word&word\\
word&word\\
word&word\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in `array-xetex-bidi.def`, line 90

```
\let\\\@arraycr \let\tabularnewline\\\let\par\@empty \if@RTLtab\hbox\bgroup\beginR\vbox\bgroup\fi\@preamble}
```

To be more precise, the bug is in

```
\if@RTLtab\hbox\bgroup\beginR\vbox\bgroup\fi
```

which unconditionally inserts the table in a `\vbox`, making irrelevant the `\vtop` started with the `[t]` option.

If I change it to

```
\if@RTLtab
  \hbox\bgroup\beginR
  \if#1t\vtop\else\vbox\fi\bgroup
\fi
```

the output is

[image]

(note: I used `\quad` instead of `\hfill` between the tables).

Temporary workaround:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@array}
  {\beginR\vbox}
  {\beginR\if#1t\vtop\else\vbox\fi}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

The patch will be unsuccessful when the bug is fixed, so it will make no harm.

Comment: did you submit bug, or should i?

Comment: @Tim Please, do.